# Saxon and setBaseOutputURI resulting in "URI has an authority component" error

Tags: java, unix, uri, saxon

I'm using saxon to create 5 html files from 1 xml file. Whenever I run the code windows, it runs smoothly and creates all the necessary files. However, when I run the code in unix, it resulted in this error:

```
Failed to create output file file:/output1.html:   Permission denied
```

Searching in stackoverflow, I learned it was trying to write into the root directory, which brought me to try setBaseOutputURI().

I'm trying to make saxon output the html files into /foo/biz/html_out, so I wrote this code:

```
String filePathUri = "file://foo/biz/html_out/";
xsltTransformer.setBaseOutputURI(filePathUri);
```

The error now reads

```
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Cannot write to URI file://foo/output1.html (URI has an authority component)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:454)
```

My questions are:

1. Did I arrive at the correct conclusion that I have to use setBaseOutputURI?
2. Am I writing the URI wrong?
3. Is there any else I should try, considering the code works fine in windows?

Answer (score 10):

Found the answer!

I had to use "file:///foo/biz/html_out" as the URI. The extra slash made the rest of the string the text the path.

Comment: Three slashes is correct. A single slash will also work, I think. Unfortunately there are no real standards for URIs in the "file" scheme; it's even hard to find the rules for each particular operating system, let alone rules that work across operating systems.